# How to add attributes to WordPress Admin Sub Menu List Items

Tags: filters, wp-admin, admin-menu

I have been trying to find a way to add a class or an id to my custom administration sub menu. I only see a class on the first menu item. I would either like to add a css class or an ID on my sub menu list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem. I just added a `span` tag in the add_submenu_page() hook and it work:

```
 add_submenu_page(
     # The slug for the parent menu page to which this sub menu belongs
     'email-service',
     # The text that't rendered in the browser title bar 
     'Breaking News Email', 
     # The text to be rendered in the menu
     '<span class="breaking-news-toggle">Breaking News Email</span>',
     # the capability required to access this menu item
     'send_email', 
     # The slug by which this sub menu is identified
     'my-email-service', 
     # the function used to display the options for this menu's page
     array(&$this, 'email_service_form') 
   );
```